# React not getting API results on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm running  into a problem in development where the page finishes loading before the data gets sent from the API. I've tried using asynchronous functions but that doesn't help even though I'm sure it should. I think I might be doing it wrong. Below is an example of a page in my app where I am experiencing this issue:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import axios from 'axios';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { Card,
         Button
 } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function SingleTour() {
    const [tour, setTour]= useState({});
    const [tourShows, setTourShows] = useState({});

    const router = useRouter();
    const {slug} = router.query;

    useEffect( () => {
        let enpoints = [
            `http://localhost:3000/tours/${slug}`,
            `http://localhost:3000/listshows/${slug}`
        ]

        axios.all(
            enpoints.map((endpoint) => 
            axios.get(endpoint)))
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            setTour(response[0].data)
            setTourShows(response[1].data)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }, [slug])

    console.log(tour);

    return (
         <div className='container'>
             <div>
                <h1></h1>
             </div>

            <h3>Shows</h3>

            <div className='card-display'>
                    {tourShows.data ? (
                        tourShows.data.map(({attributes, id}) => (
                            <Link href={`/shows/${id}`} passHref key={id}>
                                <Card border="secondary" style={{ width: '18rem', margin: '1rem'}}>
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Card.Title>Show {id}</Card.Title>
                                            <Card.Text>{attributes.date}</Card.Text>
                                            <Card.Text>{attributes.location}</Card.Text>
                                            <Card.Text>Head Count {attributes.headcount}</Card.Text>
                                    </Card.Body>  
                                </Card>               
                            </Link>
                ))
            ) : 'LOADING ...'}

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am also using Next JS if that makes a difference.

Comment: I don't understand wha you mean by the page finishes loading before the data gets sent. What is happening inside of your component ?

Comment: Are you attempting to use server-side rendering? Or is this intended to run strictly in a browser?

Comment: What I mean by finishes loading before the data gets sent is that the page will finish rendering before the data gets sent from the API. This results in undefined variables and other attributes not working the way they should because they are dependent on data that has not been received yet.

Comment: It is not clear what any issue is here. The `useEffect` hook runs at the end of the initial render and your UI code appears to handle conditionally rendering based on the `tourShows.data` state. Are your API response values really `response.data.data`?

Answer (score 1):

If you use useEffect hook it is expected that you will have a render before the hook fires to fetch the data, that is the way useEffect works.

If you want to fetch your data inside the next app you have to use getServerSideProps instead, fetch the data there and pass that as a prop to the component. See the docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Comment: Thank you for this, if I understand correctly I need to take out the useEffect and then use getServerSideProps to fetch the data and then pass those as props. My only question now is can I still do this on the same page? Or do I need to do it on another page? The docs are kind of confusing on that part.

Comment: All in the same page. The getServerSideProps run on the server side before the page is send back to the client

Answer (score 0):

This is the way React works. useEffect will attempt to fetch the data and React will continue doing it's business, render the component. You can put an if statement at the beginning of the return statement, for instance checking the length of the tourShows.data, it the length is 0 return nothing, otherwise return as you do now.

Comment: I had previously put "tourShows.data.length?" like you suggested, but I was still running into the error. The "LOADING" option was never hit because Next or React couldn't get passed "tourShows" being undefined